# jQuery sort() is not working in function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, push

I am trying to sort the array after adding new entry into the array using push().
However there are 2 errors. First the sort() is not allowed. Second is when I remove the sort() the new entry always showed with a number of 5 attached

```
<body>
<button id="addbtn">Add cars to list</button>
<p id="add"></p>

<script>
let cars = ["bmw", "honda", "toyota", "ford"];

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addbtn").click(function(){
            $("#add").show(1000);
            let newcar = [prompt("Enter new car")]
            cars += cars.push(newcar);
            cars.sort(); //here in not working
            alert(cars);
            document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = cars;
          })
    })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know what `cars += cars.push(newcar);` is doing?

Comment: @SergeySosunov I must say that line has amazing results, I mean, the way javascript interprets it is crazy

Comment: Author, `cars` after this line is a `string` which contains all the elements from array after push, separated by comma and + cars.length after it. The exact string you seeing. Replace this line with just `cars.push(newcar);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding new object into an array, you only need to use `arr.push(obj)`, and it will return the length of array (5 in your case) and by using `+=` you are changing array to string and adding the 5 at the end of it therefor the sort will not work.

So you must change your code to:

```
let cars = ["bmw", "honda", "toyota", "ford"];
const newcar = [prompt("Enter new car")]
cars.push(newcar); //Change this line (remove car +=)
cars.sort();
```

Comment: Simple and straight explanation thanks @Warjeh